# Failure while trying to append in a try statement

Tags: python, try-except

So I have a small program that reads a file and creates it if it doesn't exist.
But it fails when you try to read the contents of the second and third file and append it to the first.
I marked in the code exactly where it fails.

It always jumps to the except part, I didnt include it here because it seemed unnecesary (the except part)

```
with open ('lista1.txt','r') as file_1:
reader_0 = file_1.readlines() #reads a list of searchterms, the first search term of this list is "gt-710"

for search in reader_0:
    # creates the txt string component of the file to be created, this is the first one 
    file_0 = search.replace("\n","") +".txt" 
    file_1 = str(file_0.strip())
    
    # creates the txt string component of the file to be created, this is the second one
    files_2 = search.replace("\n","") +"2.txt" 
    file_2 = str(files_2.strip())
    
    # creates the txt string component of the file to be created, this is the second one
    files_3 = search.replace("\n","") +"3.txt" 
    file_3 = str(files_3.strip())
    
    try: #if the file named the same as the searchterm exists, read its contents    
        file = open(file_1,"r")
        file2 = open(file_2,"r")
        file3 = open(file_3,"r")

        file_contents = file.readlines()
        file_contents2 = file2.readlines()
        file_contents3 = file3.readlines()

        file = open(file_1,"a") #appends the contents of file 3 and file 2 to file 1

        print("im about here")

        file.write(file_contents2) #fails exactly here I don't know why
        file.write(file_contents3)

        file2 = open(file_2,"w+")
        file2.write(file_contents)

        file3 = open(file_3,"w+")
        file3.write(file_contents2)
```

Comment: Rather than using the `open`..`close` syntax, perhaps change to `with open(file, 'r') as fh:` syntax. Perhaps you are encountering some problems writing/reading to/from file handles that are still open elsewhere.

Comment: `file_contents2` is a list, but `write` expects a string. Use `read()` instead of `readlines()`.

Comment: If you would remove the `try/except` or simply print the error in the `except` you will see the exact error which is quite descriptive... `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it fails at the point you mention is that you are trying to write a list into the file (not a string). `file2.readlines()` returns a list of strings, each being their own line so to fix this change all the `readlines` to `filexxx.read()` which returns the whole file contents as a string.

I also recommend making the changes the other answer states to make your code more readable/robust.

Answer (score 0):

You start reading from `file_` with `file = open(file_1, 'r')`, and then open it again in append mode, without closing the first I/O operation - causing a failure when you attempt to write to the find while it's open in read mode.

Change your file reading/writing to utilize the less error-prone `with open` syntax, as follows:

```py
with open(file_1, 'r') as file_handle:
    file_contents = file_handle.read()

with open(file_2, 'r') as file_handle:
    file_contents2 = file_handle.read()

with open(file_3, 'r') as file_handle:
    file_contents3 = file_handle.read()

with open(file_1, 'a') as file_handle:
    file_handle.write(file_contents2)

# etc.
```

This syntax makes it very evident when a file is no longer open, and in what state it is open in.